# Правильное размещение IF в цикле

Tags: c#, циклы, шифрование

Здравствуйте!

Нужна ваша помощь, как быть уже не знаю (Суть в том, что шифруется введенное слово в соответствии с таблицей (буква=цифре), но есть такой момент, что определенное число букв=конкретному числу. Так, например, сочетание "CON"=12. Если во введенном слове такое сочетание есть, то оно заменяется 12, а не каждая буква в отдельности.

Код для отслеживания этого слога и замены цифрой такой есть:

```
string s1 = textBox1.Text;
string s2 = "con";
bool b;
b = s1.Contains(s2);
if (b = s1.Contains(s2))
{
    result += 12;
}
```

Код самого шифрования такой:

```
for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.Text.Length; i++)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
    {
        if (col.HeaderText == textBox1.Text[i].ToString())
        {
            result += dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[col.Index].Value;
        }
    }
}
label1.Text = "Результат: " + result;
```

Как мне правильно свести эти две части кода? А то если я внутрь пишу `if (b = s1.Contains(s2))`, то мне после каждой буквы выводится 12 или прочая ерунда...

Помогите, пожалуйста! Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: Если я правильно понял задачу, здесь лучше пользоваться методом Replace() у строки. И не придется городить никаких циклов. Приведенная выше замена записывается одной строчкой s1.Replace("CON", "12");

Comment: Гениальный алгоритм шифровки: Штирлиц - нервно курит в сторонке.

Comment: не совсем понял как и вместо чего идет этот код: 
s1.Replace("CON", "12"); ?
если я допустим добавляю result+=s1.Replace("con", "12"); в foreach, то ничего не добиваюсь, поскольку шифруется каждая буква по отдельности и после каждого числа добавляется 12...поясните плиз)
там же у меня условие i < textBox1.Text.Length и поэтому три раза 12 и добавляется(((

Comment: Вот только что обсуждали managed languages и вот яркий пример уровня вхождения.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что цикл "for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.Text.Length; i++)" cовершенно не нужен. Оставьте один цикл foreach в теле которого проводите замену методом Replace

Comment: логично, но тогда не знаю как исправить if в foreach, т.к. там заголовок столбцов таблицы сравнивается с textBox1.Text[i], а "i" у меня уже не будет, как-то это можно исправить?

Comment: @nnesterov,т.е. как у Texta элемент показать, если не [i]?

Answer (score 1):

Под рукой нет студии, поэтому с коленки

```
String str1 = "connect";
String str2=str1;
DataGridView dgw = dataGridView1;
int dgw_maxIndex = dgw.RowCount-1;
int result=0;

for(int i=dgw_maxIndex; i<=0;i++){
    if(str2.Equals("")){
        break;
    }else if(str2.Contains(dgw.Item[0,i].Value)){
        str2.Reaplce(dgw.Item[0,i].Value,"");
        result += dgw.Item[1,i].Value;
    }else{
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: у таблицы не существует такого элемента как Item...что вы имели ввиду под ним?

Comment: ну если он указал item[x,y], то, скорее всего, он имел ввиду ячейку

Comment: @wicS, @teanЫЧ прав, имел ввиду ячейку, где [0,i] - элемент словаря, а [1,i] - его замена

Comment: так и как ее исправить?я понимаю что ячейка,но студия пишет,что нет такого в данной ситуации(

Comment: @wics, я не знаю что у Вас там написано и почему это не работает - представьте код

Comment: @stck, вот это условие if (str2.Contains(dgw.Item[0, i].Value))-это на проверку введенного слово получается, я вообще просто такое не использовал( а ошибка такая, везде Item подчеркивает :"System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView" не содержит определения для "Item" и не был найден метод расширения "Item", принимающий тип "System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView" в качестве первого аргумента